# Powershell copy files based on CSV content

Tags: powershell, csv, copy-item

Any similar PowerShell script I test I get the same error: "Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null". Any idea why? Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Script**:

```
Import-CSV "C:\test\Source-Destination.csv" | 
foreach { 
Copy-item  -Path $_.Source -Destination $_.Destination -Recurse
}
```

**Error**:

```
  Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
  At line:5 char:28
+ foreach { Copy-item  -Path $_.Source -Destination $_.Destination -Rec ...
+                            ~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
  ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I have in both column’s A in B in the csv file UNC paths. In column A the Source of the file with the filename and extension and in the second column the Destination, the path to the folder on another server. Folders already exist in all cases but missing some files that need to be copied over. Also tested in all cases with local paths. I get the same error. And when debugging $*.Source and $*.Destination is empty: " $_.Source= ".

Comment: Do column a and b have a header??

Comment: please add the [sanitized] EXACT text of the 1st 3 lines of your CSV to your Question.

Comment: Ditto to Doug, but also: does the file use commas as delimiter character or something else?

Comment: @Theo: I changed the delimiter to comma's and the problem is solved. At least using local paths. I expect it would work as well with UNC paths which I will test in few days. Thank you very much!

Thank you all!

Comment: You can also use the `-Delimiter` parameter on [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) for that. No need to change the csv itself then ;)

Comment: @Theo: Yes thanks! :). I came across that in another script after I replied!